# The boolean fuzzy query in elasticsearch is not returning expected result

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to build a fuzzy bool query on first and last names in elasticsearch 7.2.0. I have a document with "asim" and "banskota" as first and last name respectively. But when I query with "asi" or "asimmm" and the exact last name, elasticsearch returns no result. However, when queried with exact first name or "asimm", it returns me the intended result from the document.

I also wrote a "fuzzy" query instead of "match". I experimented with different fuzziness parameters, but the outcome is same. Both first name and last names are analyzed, and I queried the 'analyzer' API wrt how it analyze
 'asim'. It is indexing the document with 'asim' as a single token with standard analyzer.

EDIT: It turns out that the fuzzy query works with 'Substitution' case, for example, it returns the result for 'asim' when queried with 'asmi' but not for deletion. It is surprising to me as the edit distance in the substitution is greater than in the deletion case. When the string length is greater, for instance with the last name 'Banskota', fuzzy matching works for 'deletion' case as well. What should I do to make the fuzzy search work in 'deletion' case with string length of 4 or 5?

```
fuzzy_body = {"size": 10, 
               "query":{
                   "bool":{
                      "must": [


                    {
                        "match":{"FIRST_NAME_N":{'query': 'asi',"fuzziness": "AUTO"}},

                    },

                   {
                   "fuzzy":{"LAST_NAME_N": "banskota"}
                   }
                      ]
                   }
               }
              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if the name fields are indexed as keyword type, the query returns the expected results with "AUTO" fuzziness.